# The Class/Object Paradox confusion

Tags: ruby

In the book The Well Grounded Rubyist ([excerpt](http://css.dzone.com/news/classes-as-objects-and-message)), David Black talks about the "Class/Object Chicken-and-Egg Paradox". I'm having a tough time understanding the entire concept.

Can someone explain it in better/easier/analogical/other terms?

Quote (emphasis mine):

> **The class `Class` is an instance of itself; that is, it’s a `Class`
>   object. And there’s more. Remember the class `Object`? Well, `Object`
>   is a class... but classes are objects. So, `Object` is an object. And
>   `Class` is a class. And `Object` is a class, and `Class` is an object.**
>
> Which came first? How can the class `Class` be created unless the
>   class `Object` already exists? But how can there be a class `Object`
>   (or any other class) until there’s a class `Class` of which there can
>   be instances?
>
> The best way to deal with this paradox, at least for now, is to ignore
>   it. Ruby has to do some of this chicken-or-egg stuff in order to get
>   the class and object system up and running—and then, the circularity
>   and paradoxes don’t matter. In the course of programming, you just
>   need to know that classes are objects, instances of the class called
>   `Class`.
>
> (If you want to know in brief how it works, it’s like this: every
>   object has an internal record of what class it’s an instance of, and
>   the internal record inside the object `Class` points back to `Class`.)

Comment: What part don't you understand? (EDIT: I think this is a good question and worth discussing, but I'd like to be able to focus my answer a bit.)

Comment: Sounds as totally useless, and self-inflicted problem. The question is non-sense. The answer has no use. _Best way_ ... _ignore_. Explanation is in the last sentence - it's a cyclic dependency.

Comment: To the closers: How is the question not constructive? The answer has a use - to understand this aspect of Ruby. Just because the question is confusing does not mean it is not constructive or deserves no answer!

Comment: @PlatinumAzure, the confusion starts with the paragraph in bold - i.e. what does that exactly mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can see the problem in this diagram:

[image: Ruby Method Lookup Flow]
<sub>(source: [phrogz.net](http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/RubyMethodLookupFlow.png))</sub>

All object instances inherit from `Object`. All classes are objects, and `Class` is a class, therefore `Class` is an object. However, object instances inherit from their class, and `Object` is an instance of the `Class` class, therefore `Object` itself gets methods from `Class`.

As you can see in the diagram, however, there isn't a circular lookup loop, because there are two different inheritance 'parts' to every class: the instance methods and the 'class' methods. In the end, the lookup path is sane.

*N.B.: This diagram reflects Ruby 1.8, and thus does not include the core `BasicObject` class introduced in Ruby 1.9.*

Comment: "Object inherits from Class." seems false to me. Object is an instance of Class. In 1.8, Object inherits from nil. In 1.9, Object inherits from BasicObject, which in turn inherits from nil.

Comment: @JohnDouthat You're right, the way I said that was confusing. I meant that: `class Class; def self.foo; 42; end; end; Object.foo #=> 42`

Answer (score 2):

I know that my answer comes at least 3 years late, but I have learned about Ruby quite recently and I must admit that the literature sometimes presents (in my opinion) misleading explanations, even though one is handling a very simple problem. Moreover, I am (and was) surprised by such appalling phrases as:

```
    "The best way to deal with this paradox, at least for now, is to ignore it."
```

stated by the author D. Black, and quoted in the question, but this attitude seems to be pervasive. I have experienced this tendency within the physics community but I have not suspected it had also spread through the programming one. I am not stating that nobody understands what is lurking behind, but it seems at least intriguing why not providing the (indeed) very simple and precise answer, as in this case there is one, without invoking any obscure words such as "paradox" within the explanation.

This so-called "paradox" (even though it is definitely NOT such thing) comes from the (at least misleading) belief that "being an instance of (a subclass of)" should be something as "being an element of" (in, say, naive set theory), or in other terms, a class (in Ruby) is the set containing all the objects sharing some common property (for instance, under this naive interpretation the class String includes all the string objects). Even though this naive point of view (which I may call the "membership interpretation") may help understanding isolated (and rather easy) classes such as String or Symbol, it indeed PRODUCES A CLEAR CONTRADICTION with our naive understanding (and also the axiomatic one, for it contradicts Von Neumann's regularity axiom of set theory, if someone knows what I am talking about) of the membership relationship, for an object could not be an element of itself, as the previous interpretation implies when regarding the object Class.

The previously stated problem is easily avoided if one gets rid of such misleading membership interpretation with a very simply minded model as follows. 
I would have guess that my following explanation is well-known by the experts, so I claim no originality at all, but perhaps it was not rephrased in the (simple) terms I am going to present it: in some sense I am completely astonished that (apparently) nobody stated in these terms from the very beginning, and my intention is just to highlight what I believe is the basic underlying structure.

Let us consider a set O of (basic) objects, which consists of all the (basic) objects Ruby has, provided with a mapping f from O to O (which is more or less the .class method), satisfying that the image of the composition of f with itself has only one element. 
This latter element (or object) is denoted Class (indeed, what you know to be the class Class). 
I would be tempted to write this post using LaTeX code but I am not quite sure if it will be parsed and converted into typical math expressions. 
The image of the mapping f is (by definition) the set of Ruby classes (e.g. String, Object, Symbol, Class, etc). 
Ruby programmers (even though if they do not know it) interpret the previous construction as follows: we say that an object "x is an instance of y" if and only if y = f(x). By the way this tells us you exactly that Class is an instance of Class (i.e. of itself).

Now, we would need much more decorations to this simple model in order to get the full Ruby hierarchy of classes and functionality (imposing the existence of some fixed members on the image of the map f, a partial order on the image of the map f in order to define subclasses to get afterwards inheritance, etc), and in particular to get the nice picture that was interestingly upvoted, but I suppose that everybody can figure this out from the primitive model I gave (I have written some pages explaining this for myself, after having read several Ruby manuals. I may provide a copy if anybody finds it useful).

Comment: Given your obvious dedication, I do not want to downvote you. Like you, I am also a fan of long sentences, if necessary. But your second paragraph (This so-called "paradox"...) is plain unreadable. Your answer is too long for what it says. Also, maybe you are a physics genius, but you are quite new to Ruby by your own admission, and your seniority on SO is very low. If you spent more time observing SO ways, you would know that hardly anyone will read an essay this long under 3 years old question. It would be more beneficial for you if you wrote this on your blog, ...

Comment: ... where you could also make sure that your LaTeX formulas would be displayed correctly. The title of the post could be "Ruby class hierarchy from set-theoretic viewpoint" and if you write 4 more posts like that, people will start finding you an consider you a minor authority on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. First, let me say I am no genius at all, and I do not even consider it to be important, for I try to avoid fallacious ad hominem reasoning. Second, I have been told several times I perhaps use too many brackets in my writings, so I might admit it takes some time to parse my sentences. OTOH, my intention in posting this answer was to help someone (like me) who finds some of the typical hocus pocus in Ruby manuals quite confusing. The (up- or down-)votes and the seniority of this interesting web page are not of my concern (without any intention of offense),...

Comment: (...), as I guess that it is enough for me if someone finds the post useful, by analyzing what it says. If SO (e.g. the administrators) believes the post should be deleted, I completely agree.

Answer (score 1):

In practical terms, all you need to understand is that *Object* is the mother of all classes. All classes extend *Object*. It is this relationship that you will use in programming, understanding inheritance and so forth.

Eg; You can call **hash()** on any instance of any object at any time? Why? Because that function appears in the *Object* class, and all classes inherit that function, because all classes extend *Object*.

As far as the idea of *Class* goes, this comes up much less frequently. An object of class *Class* is like a blueprint, it's like having the class in your hands, without creating an instance of it. There's a little more to it, but it's a difficult one to describe without a lengthy example. Rest assured, when (if ever) the time comes to use it, you'll see it's purpose.

All this excerpt is saying is that *Object* has a class of type *Class* and *Class* is an object, so must extend *Object*. Its cyclic, but it's irrelevant. The answer is buried somewhere in the compiler.

Comment: `Object` inherits from `BasicObject` in 1.9, and I'd say that classes arise very frequently in normal ruby programming.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the *which-came-first* criterion, there are two kinds of Ruby objects:

- **Built-in** objects. They exist at the start of a Ruby program and can be considered to have zero creation time.
- **User created** objects. They are created after the program starts via object creation methods (new/clone/dup, class-definition, module-definition, literal-constructs, ...). Such objects are linearly ordered by their time of creation. This order happens to inversely correspond to class-inheritance and instance-of relations.

A detailed explanation of the Ruby object model is available at [www.atalon.cz](http://www.atalon.cz/rb-om/ruby-object-model/).

Answer (score 1):

**Which came first: The *class Class* or the *class Object*?**

Every class is an instance of the class Class. It follows that the *class Object* is an instance of the *class Class*. So you need the *class Class* to create the *class Object*. Therefore:

> 1. The *class Class* **exists before** the *class Object*.

---

The *class Class* is a subclass of the *class Object*. So you need the *class Object* from which the *class Class* can be created. Therefore:

> 2. The *class Object* **exists before** the *class Class*.

So statement-2 conflicts with statement-1 and so we have our chicken & egg dilemma. Or you can just accept it as a circular definition!

Comment: @WillSheppard Assuming my answer is correct, then on the surface, yes and I rather like it. How it's setup and structured internally to work like this externally probably allays the contradiction:(

Answer (score 0):

I have done a dig into the source code of Ruby and created [this post](https://techconative.com/blog/ruby-class-mental-model/) on how to make sense of it.