# Ruby Object Model / Class / Modules .... diagram anywhere?

Tags: ruby

I have been thinking about making my own diagram to better put my head around how all the classes and modules in Ruby inherit from each other.  How it all ties together visually. I am sure there is a good one out there. I Googled it but was not satisfied with the results. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's a diagram in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675774/the-class-object-paradox-confusion/7676029#7676029

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am also a visual learner and ended up drawing my own "homemade" diagram:

[image: Ruby Object Model]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best explanations and diagrammatic explanation of the ruby object model can be found in this book:  [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby)  I tried googling the relevant pages but came up empty

Comment: that book's writing style is just aweful - I would not recommend it, although the concepts in it are important. This book it truly painful to read!!

Comment: @RichRamm: Feel free to voice your opinion on the book [in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236191/what-will-i-learn-from-metaprogramming-ruby), but are you saying the diagrammatic explanation itself is bad?

Comment: @RichRamm: As the book was published by the Pragmatic Programmers, which includes Dave Thomas, I suggest you get rid of the sneer quotes around `borrowed`.

Answer (score 0):

For a good understanding on how the Ruby Object Model and Metaprogramming work, I would highly recommend these ScreenCasts by Pragmatic Programmer's Dave Thomas:

http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming

Dave Thomas is awesome at explaining the concepts, and the screencasts have nice graphics in them visualizing how things relate to each other..  those ScreenCasts are straight to the point, without distractions - and are worth every penny, err cent!

There is also a book "Metaprogramming Ruby" http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby
but although it covers a lot of concepts, the book is badly written, and through it's writing style makes it really hard to memorize the concepts / or use the book as a reference to look up things later..

Answer (score 0):

A diagram showing superclass and eigenclass links between Ruby objects (but not the module inclusion links) is available at [www.atalon.cz](http://www.atalon.cz/rb-om/ruby-object-model/#sc-inheritance-sample).

Since 11 January 2012 there is a [diagram](http://www.atalon.cz/rb-om/ruby-object-model/#s2-example) containing module inclusion links.