# Ruby metaclass confusion

Tags: ruby, metaclass

I understand that all classes in ruby are instances of metaclass Class. And that "regular" objects are instances of these classes (the instances of metaclass Class).

But I keep wondering, I mean classes are root of objects, classes are themselves instances of Class (called metaclass because its instances are classes). I saw in some blogs some overriding of method `new`, of class Class.

So Class behaves as a class, but its instances are classes. So it seems we have a circle, it looks likes class Class is an instance of itself.

I'm clearly missing a point here. What is the origin of class Class?

Here's an example that's confusing me:

```
class Class
  def new
    #something
  end
end
```

But keyword `class` implies an instance of class Class. So how do this work?

Comment: `Class.class # => Class`

Comment: It's turtles all the way down!

Comment: See also [The class/object paradox confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675774/the-class-object-paradox-confusion).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> how do this work

Easy: it doesn't. Not in Ruby, anyway.

Just like in most other languages, there are some core entities that are simply assumed to exist. They fall from the sky, materialize out of thin air, magically appear.

In Ruby, some of those magic things are:

- `Object` doesn't have a superclass, but you cannot define a class with no superclass, the implicit direct superclass is always `Object`. [Note: there may be implementation-defined superclasses of `Object`, but eventually, there will be one which doesn't have a superclass.]
- `Object` is an instance of `Class`, which is a subclass of `Object` (which means that indirectly `Object` is an instance of `Object` itself)
- `Class` is a subclass of `Module`, which is an instance of `Class`
- `Class` is an instance of `Class`

None of these things can be explained in Ruby.

`BasicObject`, `Object`, `Module` and `Class` all need to spring into existence at the same time because they have circular dependencies.

Just because this relationship cannot be expressed in Ruby code, doesn't mean the Ruby Language Specification can't say it has to be so. It's up to the implementor to figure out a way to do this. After all, the Ruby implementation has a level of access to the objects that you as a programmer don't have.

For example, the Ruby implementation could first create `BasicObject`, setting both its `superclass` pointer and its `class` pointer to `null`.

Then, it creates `Object`, setting its `superclass` pointer to `BasicObject` and its `class` pointer to `null`.

Next, it creates `Module`, setting its `superclass` pointer to `Object` and its `class` pointer to `null`.

Lastly, it creates `Class`, setting its `superclass` pointer to `Module` and its `class` pointer to `null`.

Now, we can overwrite `BasicObject`'s, `Object`'s, `Module`'s, and `Class`'s `class` pointer to point to `Class`, and we're done.

This is easy to do from outside the system, it just looks weird from the inside.

Once they *do* exist, however, it is perfectly possible to implement most of their behavior in plain Ruby. You only need very barebones versions of those classes, thanks to Ruby's open classes, you can add any missing functionality at a later time.

In your example, the `class Class` is not creating a new class named `Class`, it is reopening the *existing* class `Class`, which was given to us by the runtime environment.

So, it is perfectly possible to explain the default behavior of `Class#new` in plain Ruby:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate # another magic thing that cannot be explained in Ruby
    obj.initialize(*args, &block)
    return obj
  end
end
```

[Note: actually, `initialize` is private, so you need to use `obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block)` to circumvent the access restriction.]

BTW: `Class#allocate` is another one of those magic things. It allocates a new empty object in Ruby's object space, which is something that cannot be done in Ruby. So, `Class#allocate` is something that has to be provided by the runtime system as well.

Comment: I think you mean "`BasicObject`'s superclass is `nil`", as `Object`'s superclass is `BasicObject`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: That's new in 1.9. 1.8 only has `Object` without `BasicObject`.

Comment: @HolgerJust True, but 1.8 is near end-of-life, and unless the asker specifies I assume the newest version of Ruby.

Comment: Technically, the Ruby Language Specification does not say that `Object`'s *direct* superclass is `nil`, only that *eventually* one of `Object`'s ancestors' superclass is `nil`. That way, Ruby 1.9's `BasicObject` or MacRuby's `NSObject` are still compliant with the Specification.

Comment: method superclass returns the superclass of class, or nil. it doesn't mean nil is supperclass...

Comment: @Fivell: You're right, I misremembered that. Here's the relevant quote from the Ruby Language Specification (clause 15.2.1.2): "The class `Object` does not have a direct superclass, or may have an implementation-defined superclass."

Answer (score 4):

There is a meta-circularity given by the "twist" link. It is the built-in superclass link from the root's eigenclass to the `Class` class. This can be expressed by

```
BasicObject.singleton_class.superclass == Class
```

A clue to understanding the `.class` map is seeing this map as derived from the eigenclass and superclass links: for an object `x`, `x.class` is the first class in the superclass chain of `x`'s eigenclass. This can be expressed by

```
x.class == x.eigenclass.superclass(n)
```

where `eigenclass` is a "conceptual alias" of `singleton_class`
(resistant to issues with immediate values), `y.superclass(i)` means `i`-th superclass of `y` and `n` is smallest such that `x.eigenclass.superclass(n)` is a class. Equivalently, eigenclasses in the superclass chain of `x.eigenclass` are skipped (see [rb_class_real](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/object.c?v=1.9.3#147) which also reveals that in MRI, even `superclass` links are implemented indirectly – they arise by skipping "*iclasses*").
This results in that the `class` of every class (as well as of every eigenclass) is constantly the `Class` class.

A picture is provided by [this diagram](http://www.atalon.cz/rb-om/ruby-object-model/#s2-example).

The metaclass confusion has 2 main sources:

- **Smalltalk**. The Smalltalk-80 object model contains conceptual inconsistencies that are rectified by the Ruby object model. In addition, Smalltalk literature uses dialectics in terminology, which unfortunately has not been sufficiently remedied in the Ruby literature.
- The **definition of metaclass**. At present, the definition states that *metaclasses are classes of classes*. However, for so called "*implicit metaclasses*" (the case of Ruby and Smalltalk-80) a much more fitting definition would be that of **meta-objects** of classes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Class is an instance of itself. It's a subclass of Module, which is also an instance of class, and Module is a subclass of Object, which is also an instance of Class. It is indeed quite circular — but this is part of the core language, not something in a library. The Ruby runtime itself doesn't have the same limits thast you or I do when we're writing Ruby code.

I've never heard the word "metaclass" used to talk about Class, though. It isn't used much in Ruby at all, but when it is, it's usually a synonym for what's officially called a "singleton class of an object," which is an even more confusing topic than Object-Module-Class triangle.

Comment: Indeed Class can be called a metaclass, according to the general definition. But the world metaclass i mistakingly used for others things by many rubyist. But these metaclasses are weak metaclasses according to general definition.                                                      If i remember well the things often called metaclass in ruby are singletons holding the class methods. I have read several posts about it, saying the word metaclass was mistakingly used, and they were blaming rails team on this point. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is a little out of date, [this article by _why](http://viewsourcecode.org/why/hacking/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html) may help in understanding the behavior. You can find an even deeper dive into the subject in Paolo Perrotta's [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby).

Comment: What Why is talking about there has nothing to do with Parello's use of the word "metaclass." What he's talking about is the singleton class or, more colloquially, eigenclass.