# Which comes first in Ruby the Class or the BasicObject?

Tags: ruby, oop, class, inheritance, object

At first glance I thought `BasicObject` just "lays" the `Class` (read: `Class` inherits from `BasicObject`)

```
Class.ancestors #=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Module.ancestors #=> [Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Object.ancestors #=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
BasicObject.ancestors #=>[BasicObject]
```

But things suddenly became quite curious.

```
Class.class #=> Class
Module.class #=> Class
Object.class #=> Class
BasicObject.class #=> Class
```

"Aha! I thought. "We're really making an instance of `Class`: `BasicObject = Class.new`. But then I remembered that all these instances sit in a hierarchy with `Class` at the bottom: `Class < Module < Object < Kernel < BasicObject`.

Each of these classes are simultaneously objects.  In turn, system seems highly circular. Where hierarchy begin and how does it blend with itself to form the abstract constructs of Ruby?

Comment: I'd like to reference [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10526013/512904) by [Jörg W Mittag](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/jorg-w-mittag). I think it provides a very good description of the relationships between Ruby's fundamental classes.

Comment: An illuminating quote from that answer: "BasicObject, Object, Module and Class all need to spring into existence at the same time because they have circular dependencies."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, everything is an Object (< BasicObject), and so is class. A class is an object of class Class. An object of class Object is not necessarilly a class. However, class Object is a Class, necessarilly, and so is class BasicObject. Understood? No? Let's move on. (As Matz says in his intro :)))

(In other words, you got it right.)

Answer (score 2):

Re opening zombie question to add my beautiful diagram :)

```
*Class*
  ↓
BasicObject ~= 'Parent class of all classes but "inherits" from [Class] - causing an interrelated loop'
  ↓
Object      ~= Class.new(BasicObject) {}
  ↓
Module      ~= Class.new(Object) {}
  ↓
*Class*     ~= Class.new(Module) {}
```