# The Class Superclass and Subclass Structure of Ruby

Tags: ruby

The Class has the superclass Module, which has the superclass Object, which has the superclass BasicObject, which is an instance of Class. And Class is again a subclass of Module.

I'm really confused regarding this.(the above was gleaned from using the .class and .superclass methods on each of the above objects)

Can anyone explain to me what exactly is going on here?

Comment: What are you confused about? Your description above is correct. What you described correctly is exactly what is going on.

Comment: Also check out [Class SuperClass Paradox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558504/can-someone-explain-the-class-superclass-class-superclass-paradox) and [Ruby Metaclass Confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525053/ruby-metaclass-confusion).

Comment: I'd recommend the ScreenCast series by the Pragmatic Programmers on The Ruby Object Model and Metaprogramming: 
http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "instance of" is a small but significant part of the mental gymnastics you need to do here.

That, and objects of type `Class`, and a class called `Object`.

If you can understand these, at least while repeating to yourself slowly, then you have got it:

- `Object.new` creates an instance of class *Object*
- `Object` is a reference to the class *Object*, which is itself an object of class *Class*
- `Class` is a reference the class *Class*, which is also an object of class *Class* (!)
- `Class.new` creates an instance of class *Class*.

  - This is part of what happens under the hood when you write `class Foo`
  - In fact `Foo = Class.new( String )` is much the same as `class Foo < String; end`
- The class hierarchy of `Class`, `Module`, `Object` is an implementation detail in Ruby. Almost all classes inherit from `Object`, so it is no real surprise that `Class` does so too.

The rest is just repeated use and experience.

It is worth noting something else going on here: The labels in the code you type are symbols/variable names, which are *pointers* to the underlying objects which have types and contain data. There is no requirement to use those labels directly, they are pretty much the same as any other Ruby variable:

```
o_klass = Object
o_instance = o_klass.new
o_instance.class
 => Object
```