# Initialization Order of Ruby class Class and class Module

Tags: ruby, class, oop

There is an apparent contradiction that I can't make sense of regarding the relationship between class Class and class Module in Ruby.

Here is the reasoning that confuses me:

**Premise Set #1**

1. Module is an instance of class Class
2. Therefore, class Class must be defined before class Module

**Premise Set #2**

1. class Class is a child class of class Module
2. Therefore, class Module must be defined before class Class.

Which of these claims is wrong / what am I missing here?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675774/the-class-object-paradox-confusion), especially the checkmarked answer.  Also @JörgWMittag provides a good explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525053/ruby-metaclass-confusion).

Comment: Your premises are still too complicated, you can construct an even simpler contradiction: `Class` is an instance of `Class`.